# show progress in gensim LdaMulticore

Tags: python, gensim

I'm using the function  `gensim.models.LdaMulticore` for training an LDA model on a large corpus. The problem is I have no idea when it's going to finish the process. Is there a way to show the progress in the process in this function?

Comment: If you enable logging at the `INFO` level, is any useful progress info shown in logs?

Comment: @gojomo no it's not making any difference

Comment: If you're using LdaModel, you can simply create perplexity_logger. But for multicore it seems not to work. 
`perplexity_logger = PerplexityMetric(corpus=common_corpus, logger='shell')

lda = LdaModel(common_corpus, id2word=common_dictionary, num_topics=5, callbacks=[perplexity_logger])`